# How to set disabled in MVC htmlAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When using an HTML Helper, what is the best method to set an attribute based on a condition. For example

```
<%if (Page.User.IsInRole("administrator")) {%>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class='contactDetails'}%>
<%} else {%>
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class='contactDetails', disabled = true}%>
<%}%>
```

There must be a better way to programmatically add just one additional KeyPair to the anonymous type? Can't use

```
new { .... disabled = Page.User.IsInRole("administrator") ... }
```

as the browser takes any disabled attribute value as making the input disabled

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  `Page.User.IsInRole(...)` doesn't work?

Comment: No error - just trying to reduce the amount of duplicate code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207597/155899

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I could suggest you to use mvccontrib.FluentHtml.

You can do something like this

```
 <%=this.TextBox(m=>m.FirstNam ).Disabled(Page.User.IsInRole("administrator"))%>
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty. Definately checking that out this weekend!

Answer (score 14):

It works for me as well...

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("SportID", (SelectList)ViewData["SportsSelectList"], "-- Select --", new { @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })%>

<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { @disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })%>
```

Answer (score 8):

Page.User.IsInRole("administrator") ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" }

Comment: I need other attributes - code repetition is what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 4):

Using @SLaks suggestion to use an Extension method, and using [Jeremiah Clark's example Extension method](http://blogs.msdn.com/miah/archive/2008/11/10/checkboxlist-helper-for-mvc.aspx) I've written an extension method so I can now do

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName,new{class='contactDetails', ...},Page.User.IsInRole("administrator"));
```

Not Sure if there's a better method though

```
public static class InputExtensions
{

    public static IDictionary<string, object> TurnObjectIntoDictionary(object data)
    {
        var attr = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (data == null)
            return dict;
        foreach (var property in data.GetType().GetProperties(attr))
        {
            if (property.CanRead)
            {
                dict.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(data, null));
            }
        }
        return dict;

    }

    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> values =  TurnObjectIntoDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        if (disabled)
            values.Add("disabled","true");


        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, values);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> values = TurnObjectIntoDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        if (disabled)
            values.Add("disabled", "true");


        return htmlHelper.TextAreaFor(expression, values);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool disabled)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> values = TurnObjectIntoDictionary(htmlAttributes);

        if (disabled)
            values.Add("disabled", "true");


        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should replace your `TurnObjectIntoDictionary` method with a `RouteValueDictionary`, which is what all of the extension methods use.  It should be faster.  Also, you should accept my answer.

Comment: BTW, anyone trying this will need 'using System.Web.Mvc' and 
'using System.Web.Mvc.Html'

Comment: FYI, you can now use the `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)` function, which returns a `RouteValueDictionary`. The reason I had to use this function, instead of `TurnObjectIntoDictionary(htmlAttributes)` is that `TurnObjectIntoDictionary` wasn't converting properties like `data_bind = "foo"` to `data-bind="foo"` in the generated HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pass a `Dictionary<string, object>`, and add the `disabled` key inside an `if` statement.

I recommend making an overload of the extension method that takes a `bool disabled` parameter and adds it to a [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) created from the attributes parameter if it's `true`.  (You could also remove the `disabled` entry from the `RouteValueDictionary` if it's `false`, and not take another parameter)

Comment: If you do that it will still render out a "disabled" attribute and most browsers will treat that as disabled regardless of disabled="disabled"

Comment: Then you'll need to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You may also define this param that way:

```
Page.User.IsInRole("administrator")
  ? (object)new { @class='contactDetails'} 
  : (object)new { @class='contactDetails', disabled = true}
```

Comment: It's the code repetition I'm trying to avoid - when you have a lot of attributes this gets just as messy

Comment: Not sure I really like the readability of it also, but when using anonymous types you have to create multiple instances for each set of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider writing your own HtmlHelper Extension class with a new TextBox method:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string cssClass, bool disabled)
    {
        return disabled 
            ? Html.TextBoxFor(expression, new {@class=cssClass, disabled="disabled"})
            : Html.TextBoxFor(expression, new {@class=cssClass})
    }
}
```

now (if this new class is in the same namespace, or you've imported the new namespace to your page header, or in the pages section of the web.config) you can do this on your aspx page:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, "contactDetails", Page.User.IsInRole("administrator")) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Created an extension method on Object that will create a copy of the input object excluding any properties that are null, and return it all as dictionary that makes it easily used in MVC HtmlHelpers:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> StripAnonymousNulls(this object attributes)
{
   var ret = new Dictionary<string, object>();
   foreach (var prop in attributes.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      var val = prop.GetValue(attributes, null);
      if (val != null)
         ret.Add(prop.Name, val);
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Not sure about performance implications of reflecting through properties twice, and don't like the name of the extension method much, but it seems to do the job well ...

```
new {
       @class = "contactDetails",
       disabled = Page.User.IsInRole("administrator") ? "true" : null
    }.StripAnonymousNulls()
```