# MVC : Set disabled or no for a textbox in HTMLAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary

In my HTML file, I have a textbox which must be disabled or enable, depending on my controller value. 
No problem to set it in disabled mode, but to set it enable...

this is my code :

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.test, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "disabled", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "MyTest" ? "" : "disabled"}}
```

I have seen some ideas on this question  : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499835/how-to-set-disabled-in-mvc-htmlattribute)

mvccontrib.FluentHtml or InputExtensions are the single solutions, to answer to my question ???

Im using "disabled" but I can use "read-only" attribute... the goal of this code is not to allow the user to fill the text box...

Thanks for your advices on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just break the line apart into something like this:

```
<% 
if (MyConditionIsTrue) 
    Response.Write(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.test, new { disabled = "true" }));
else 
    Response.Write(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.test));
%>
```

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks for your answers. I suppose the 3 are goods, but Johannes's is the more simple to applicate.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good candidate for a custom HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
    {
        var controller = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (string.Equals(controller, "MyTest", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            htmlAttributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(ex, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html.CustomTextBoxFor(model => model.test) %>
```

Comment: Perfect example for htmlhelper creation which uses Model.

Comment: it seems to be a part of code interessant, Im not used to program. Where do I need to paste this code ? I mean, which folder ?

Answer (score 0):

People love Html helpers, but you don't **have** to use them.

```
@if (MyConditionIsTrue) {
  <input id="test" name="test" value="@Model.test" disabled="disabled" />
}
else {
  <input id="test" name="test" value="@Model.test" />
}
```

If you have to reuse this logic many times, a html helper is probably a good idea.  If you're just doing it once, it might not be.

Comment: I would like to understand, why people dont have to use Html Helpers ?

Comment: By the way, the "@" is not from the initial language of MVC, no ?

Comment: Or `<input name="test" value="@Model.test" @(MyConditionIsTrue ? "disabled" : "") />`

Answer (score 0):

```
disabled
or
disabled = disabled
or
disabled = true
or
disabled = false
or
disabled = enable
```

all of the above means disabled.

remove disabled from the element to enable that.

```
if(condition)
   <input .... disabled/>
else
   <input ..... />
```