# Strategy to prevent users from updating readonly viewmodel properties by Role/Permission on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, model-binding

The platform is ASP.NET MVC 2.

We have a user story that states:

> On the [view], don't allow a user to edit [property] unless the user is
>   a [proper role]. They still must be able to view the [property].

So, I must show the field for these people, just prevent them from changing or updating the property value.

[I know that I can place a read only control in the view using an attribute for the current user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499835/how-to-set-disabled-in-mvc-htmlattribute/2499909#2499909) That should give the client a visual cue that edits are not permitted. But a CSS style won't prevent someone from hacking their post to alter the property's value.

My question pertains to protecting the property on the server side. What methods can I employ to detect changes to my incoming view model in this situation -- where a user can't edit a certain property?

**EDIT**

I would need to stay away from binds and whitelists -- I appreciate the ideas! They caused me to realize that I omitted a key piece of information.

My product owner wishes to add properties willy-nilly and at their pleasure -- which I took to read: non-static solutions need not apply. Additionally, she wishes to apply other conditional logic to their application -- "if the state of a related property is 'X', then they can edit regardless of permission", etc. I can handle that part. I just need to know where to dynamically apply them.

I am thinking that this is a custom model binder solution.

BTW, we append this particular permission to the roles:

```
var hasPermission = User.IsInRole(permission);
```

Comment: I would suggest a custom IsInRole validation rule for your properties which ignores changes to the model if the rule fails.

Comment: @Todd - Thanks for the tip. Hadn't thought of validation rules.

A model binding solution forces me to evaluate the PropertyInfo for the existence of my target attribute before I can check. In the validation rule, I already know to perform the check because the attribute itself triggers it. Will check this out and get back.

Comment: @Todd - not seeing this either. I need to check to see if the value of the model has changed against this entity in the persistence. If I put the attribute on the property, I can't get at the parent object type and ID, nor retrieve the appropriate data access object. I don't want this attribute decorating at the class level. Maybe I need to google harder for a likewise example.

Comment: @Todd - I'm still interested in your comment. Could you post any links that clarify the direction you were sending me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the custom model binder was the way to go. I can already disable the HTML controls. But I need to selectively authorize them.

I know the example object is contrived -- surely, you wouldn't have users post an object with two uneditable properties -- but the point is that I don't want to allow the user to persist their value. I will NULL out any value and then not update any NULL values. By ignoring NULL values, I don't have to go to the data access to retrieve the current value for replacement of the offending update.

This code has me on my way (using [MSPEC](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) as the testing framework):

```
public class TestSplitDetailViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CanEdit]
    public string RestrictedProperty { get; set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class CanEditAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class CanEditAttributeBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private readonly ISecurityTasks _securityTask;

    private readonly ISecurityContext _securityContext;

    public CanEditAttributeBinder(ISecurityTasks securityTask, ISecurityContext securityContext)
    {
        this._securityTask = securityTask;
        this._securityContext = securityContext;
    }

    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        var canEditAttribute = propertyDescriptor.Attributes
          .OfType<CanEditAttribute>()
          .FirstOrDefault();

        if (canEditAttribute != null)
        {
            bool allowed = IsAllowed();
            if (allowed)
            {
                propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, null);
            }
            else
            {
                base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
        }
    }

    private bool IsAllowed()
    {
        return !this._securityTask.DoesUserHaveOperation(this._securityContext.User.Username, UserOperations.ReclassAllowed);
    }
}

public class TestModelSpec : Specification<CanEditAttributeBinder>
{
    protected static HomeController controller;
    private static MockRepository mocks;

    protected static ISecurityTasks securityTasks;
    private static ISecurityContext securityContext;

    protected static ModelBindingContext bindingContext;

    Establish context = () =>
    {
        ServiceLocatorHelper.AddUserServiceWithTestUserContext();
        securityTasks = DependencyOf<ISecurityTasks>().AddToServiceLocator();
        securityContext = DependencyOf<ISecurityContext>().AddToServiceLocator();

        user = new User("CHUNKYBACON");
        securityContext.User = user;

        // When we restricted access on the client, 
        // Chunky submitted a FORM POST in which he HACKED a value 
        var formCollection = new NameValueCollection
                { 
                    { "TestSplitDetailViewModel.Id", "2" }, 
                    { "TestSplitDetailViewModel.RestrictedProperty", "12" } // Given this is a hacked value
                };

        var valueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(formCollection, null);
        var modelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(TestSplitDetailViewModel));

        bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext
        {
            ModelName = "TestSplitDetailViewModel",
            ValueProvider = valueProvider,
            ModelMetadata = modelMetadata
        };

        controller = new HomeController(null, null, null, null, null);
        mocks = new MockRepository();
        MvcMockHelpers.SetFakeControllerContext(mocks, controller);
    };

    protected static User user;

    protected static TestSplitDetailViewModel incomingModel;
}

public class when_a_restricted_user_changes_a_restricted_property : TestModelSpec
{
    private Establish context = () => securityTasks.Stub(st =>
                               st.DoesUserHaveOperation(user.Username, UserOperations.ReclassAllowed)).Return(false);


    Because of = () => incomingModel = (TestSplitDetailViewModel)subject.BindModel(controller.ControllerContext, bindingContext);

    It should_null_that_value_out = () => incomingModel.RestrictedProperty.ShouldBeNull();
}

public class when_an_unrestricted_user_changes_a_restricted_property : TestModelSpec
{
    private Establish context = () => securityTasks.Stub(st =>
                               st.DoesUserHaveOperation(user.Username, UserOperations.ReclassAllowed)).Return(true);


    Because of = () => incomingModel = (TestSplitDetailViewModel)subject.BindModel(controller.ControllerContext, bindingContext);

    It should_permit_the_change = () => incomingModel.RestrictedProperty.ShouldEqual("12");
}
```

**EDIT**

This is now my answer. I see where some might question my testing DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty. I am testing my custom override.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Bind attribute that lets you specify properties that are to be included or excluded on binding.  here is a good basic article for more information.

[Exclude attributes using Bind attribute](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/)

Comment: I updated my question to exclude static lists. The product owner will be changing when to make these readonly. I am creating a strategy for this -- an array of boolean evaluations. Still need to determine best place to apply my strategy. I think it must be a custom model binder. Looking there. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would use either a whitelist or blacklist and invoke model binding explicitly on your model. e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
var item = db.GetByID(id); // get from DB
var whitelist = [ "Name", "Title", "Category", etc ]; // setup the list of fields you want to update

UpdateModel(item, whitelist);
}
```